# PHP Bcrypt Retrieve Password

Tags: php, bcrypt

So after someone registers on the site, I use bcrypt to encrypt their password which gets stored in the password column of the database. Now if they forgot their password, I want to email them the password so they can login and change it. How do I reverse the bcrypt encryption to get the original password back?

Comment: I think that a better idea is to reset their password with a random string giving them the possibility to change it from their user panel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bcrypt is a one-way hash. You cannot decrypt it. What you can do is send them a reset link which, when clicked, will allow them to set a new password.

Answer (score 5):

You have not understood the fundamental working of `bcrypt`. If there would be a simple reverse function, nobody would use `bcrypt` any longer. Use a password reset procedure instead of sending plaintext passwords.

Please see the [Forgot Password Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet.html).