# laravel decryption on view

Tags: php, laravel

I have view where Admin can edit the user's info (name, email and password) but I get the password encrypted

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X37EB.png]

This is my view code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <strong>Password:</strong>
    {!! Form::text('password', null, array('placeholder' => 'password','class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
```

and thanks.

Comment: What encryption method did you use to insert to a table. As a example `sha1()`. Use your encryption method in placeholder. Like this: `sha1(password)`.

Comment: i used 
'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

Comment: You won't be able to edit the password! Better would be to reset the password

Comment: Do you want to get plain text or show as a password(not a text). If you want to get as plain text you cannot do that in `bcrypt`. refer:

  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084728/php-bcrypt-retrieve-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passwords in Laravel are stored as one way (bcrypt) hashes, they are not encrypted, and therefore cannot be decrypted by design.

You cannot get a plain text copy of a user's password. This is good security practice.

Just allow your admin to create a new one and store it using the hashing helper

```
Hash::make($request->newPassword);
```

Comment: i used 
'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

Comment: Yes that is a shortcut helper method, it does exactly the same thing as my example.

Comment: Hashing is a one way process - you cannot get the plaintext password after it is hashed.
Encryption is a two way process - it is possible to get the plaintext password after it is encrypted. and i used the encyption

Comment: source:
[link](https://laravel.io/forum/04-04-2014-unhashing-the-password)

Comment: Which is exactly what i said in my answer.

Comment: If you used `bcrypt()` you have hashed the password, not encrypted it.

Comment: what i need to use instead then?

Comment: If you are using the default laravel authentication, then you can't use anything else unless you also store the password in a second field and encrypt that. But allowing  people access to a plaintext version of a user's password is never acceptable practice.

Comment: @HassenBenabdelhafidh You should never be able to retrieve a password. It's a security hole. Do not work around this with two-way encryption. Your admins shouldn't need to know the password - build them a "masquerade" functionality to log in as the user, and/or let them set a new password.